# MySQL Error 1064 42000 while trying to create a trigger

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER moving_average 
AFTER INSERT
ON filtered_data FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO moving_average_table (pollutant_id,pollutant_value,lastUpdated,station_id)
VALUES (new.pollutant_id,avg(new.pollutant_value),new.lastUpdated,new.station_id)
END;
```

I am trying to create a trigger on the table filtered_data with this piece of code, is it syntactically wrong? I wonder why I keep on getting a syntax error 1064 42000. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: INSERT statement have lost its terminating `;`. But your trigger contains one statement - so remove BEGIN and END. PS. `new.pollutant_value` is scalar value, so AVG() makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

> if you use the mysql program to define a trigger that executes multiple statements, it is necessary to redefine the mysql statement delimiter so that you can use the ; statement delimiter within the trigger definition.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER moving_average 
AFTER INSERT
ON filtered_data FOR EACH ROW
 begin
INSERT INTO moving_average_table (pollutant_id,pollutant_value,lastUpdated,station_id)
VALUES (new.pollutant_id,avg(new.pollutant_value),new.lastUpdated,new.station_id) ;
end//
delimiter ;
```

you should remove the begin...end or redefine the delimiter

Comment: I am currently using dbeaver, the software automatically generates the delimiter tags while creating the trigger, but it still results in a syntax error.

Comment: just check, have you try the exact same string here?

Comment: Thank you for the help! Removing the begin and end solved the issue.